# How to monitor NetworkManager connectivity?

Tags: network-manager

I want to start a certain application when NetworkManager connects to certain WiFi. But from DBus, I could not find such signal from NetworkManager except a notification of libNotify.
Is there a more direct way?

Comment: I'm curious if you're still around and interested in a dbus solution. Comment if you are.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, is it possible to use DBus? I am not sure.

Comment: Kinda possible. I'll need a bit of time, but I'll update my answer once it's done and let you know

Answer (score 2):

NetworkManager includes an `nmcli` program, which has a `monitor` command. Here is what its output looks like for me when I disconnect then connect to a Wi-Fi access point:

```
$ nmcli monitor
There's no primary connection
wlp4s0: unavailable
Networkmanager is now in the 'disconnected' state
wlp4s0: disconnected
wlp4s0: using connection 'CyberShadowPC'
wlp4s0: connecting (prepare)
Networkmanager is now in the 'connecting' state
wlp4s0: connecting (configuring)
wlp4s0: connecting (need authentication)
wlp4s0: connecting (prepare)
wlp4s0: connecting (configuring)
wlp4s0: connecting (getting IP configuration)
wlp4s0: connecting (checking IP connectivity)
wlp4s0: connecting (starting secondary connections)
wlp4s0: connected
Networkmanager is now in the 'connected' state
'CyberShadowPC' is now the primary connection
```

It looks like it should be easy to parse its output and run appropriate actions as necessary. Here's a bash script which runs a command when a NetworkManager connection becomes the active primary one:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

connection_name=CyberShadowPC
command=(notify-send "Connected to $connection_name!")

LC_ALL=C nmcli monitor | \
    while read -r line
    do
        if [[ "$line" == "'$connection_name' is now the primary connection" ]]
        then
            "${command[@]}"
        fi
    done
```

Comment: To be perfectly fair, this answers only provides partial solution. OP asked for "*start a certain application when NetworkManager connects to certain WiFi*" and this only shows partial way to know if NM connected to WiFi with saying "should be easy to parse" without showing, nor starts an application. If we are talking about scripting, then this answers won't be too efficient either, as you'll need pipeline to parse and start an app ( hit, that's a while loop ) and cost in wait and fork syscalls. Sorry but this answers isn't as useful as it may seem

Comment: The OP asked "how", this answer answers; there was no mention of a specific implementation in the question. As the OP already successfully applied DBus, I'd expect that writing the implementation would be trivial for them. To that point, I added one. Hope that helps.

Comment: "If we are talking about scripting, then this answers won't be too efficient either, as you'll need pipeline to parse and start an app ( hit, that's a while loop ) and cost in wait and fork syscalls." That's completely irrelevant because connecting to a Wi-Fi, or NetworkManager events in general, do not happen often enough to be of any practical significance performance-wise. The only cost worth talking about here is resident memory usage. But, if you'd like to add an answer with a C / DBus implementation, be my guest :)

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the monitor command.

Answer (score 1):

Run

> dbus-monitor --system "type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.NetworkManager'"

Then change your wifi connection. You will get the signal that property changed. It returns a "PrimaryConnection" that is activated.

You can then query the activated connection and see if it matches the connection you are interested in.

For example:

> qdbus --system --literal org.freedesktop.NetworkManager
> /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/Whatever
> org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll
> org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active
>
> qdbus --system --literal  org.freedesktop.NetworkManager
> /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/Whatever org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get
> org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.AccessPoint.Ssid

(probably just simpler to run iwgetid -r after you detect the property change)

Comment: Thanks. But my Linux is on cable now. So cannot test.

Answer (score -2):

While it's certainly possible to use `dbus` , personally I'd go with simple bash while loop + awk

```
while [ "$(iwconfig 2> /dev/null |  awk '/Access Point/ && /XX:YY:ZZ:11:22:33/ {print "true" }')" != "true" ]; do : ; sleep 0.25 ;done ; echo DONE
```

What is happening there ? While loop keeps running, testing output of `iwconfig` filtered out with `awk`. So far as the `awk` doesn't find  the mac address of the access that you want to connect to, loop continues running. As soon as `awk` sees that you've associated with that particular AP , the test condition `[ "String1" != "String2" ]` becomes false, loop breaks , and goes on to the `echo DONE` command. Of course , `echo DONE` is what can be replaced with the program that you want to run.

This command can be ran manually or placed into a script, and the script added to the Startup Application list.

Simple, straightforward, and does the job. Like I said in the beginning, it is possible to use dbus , but is not as simple.

Comment: It is not quite suitable for me. My laptop does not shutdown often. So a Startup Application could not work. If I used a dead loop, that looks too ugly for me. Personally, I'd like some event-drive way, so I chose DBus.

Comment: Frequent use of polling loops, especially in shell scripts running persistently in the background, can noticeably affect power consumption. Not only is there the persistent waste of cycles, but timers require otherwise-idle CPUs to switch power states and increase the number of wakeups.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Yes, I agree - that's a fact with polling loops, but that's  a simple solution. I may revise this answer later ( which has posted 2 years ago ) since there's better methods.